# Different results with floor(a, b) and a // b

Tags: lua, floating-accuracy

```
--this function isn't relevant, but I included it for completeness
function gcd(a, b)
    local temp
    while b > 0 do
        temp = a % b
        a = b
        b = temp
    end
    return a
end

function extendedgcd(a, b)
    if b == 0 then
        return 1, 0, a
    end
    local x, y, d = extendedgcd(b, a % b)
    --this assertion fails for a = 568784642688024576, b = 5
    --left side gives 113756928537604915 (correct), while right side gives 113756928537604912 (wrong)
    assert(a // b == math.floor(a / b))
    --so here, I can't use math.floor
    return y, x - a // b * y, d
end

function modularinverse(e, mod)
    if gcd(e, mod) > 1 then
        return nil
    end
    local x, _, _ = extendedgcd(e, mod)
    if x < 0 then
        x = x % mod
    end
    if x * e % mod ~= 1 then
        error(string.format("Modular inverse (%d) doesn't produce 1 (e = %d, mod = %d)", x, e, mod))
    end
    return x
end

modularinverse(5, 568784642688024576)
```

For `a = 5` and `b = 568784642688024576`, the assertion in `extendedgcd` fails. I'm not an expert at FP precision, but there's a difference of 3 between the two so I don't think there's a rounding/precision error here. But I might be wrong.

Normally I'd just use `//` instead, but I can't because the target platform isn't running Lua 5.3, which is when the operator was added.

What am I missing? How do I make it work with `floor`, or is there another way?

Also of note: The same issue happened when I rewrote it in Python to fiddle (with `math.floor` and `//`).

Comment: In Lua 5.1/5.2 you are limited with numbers `-2^53 .. 2^53`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A more precise answer:**

As paper and pencil will show:
`568784642688024576 / 5 = 113756928537604915.02`

The most accurate binary representation of that quotient as a double precision number is:

`0100001101111001010000100101010100101110010000111001001100110011`

Which, in decimal, is: `1.13756928537604912E17` (notice the ...912 ending)

Now, if you decrease the binary representation by one, like this:

`0100001101111001010000100101010100101110010000111001001100110010`

Then it equals: `1.13756928537604896E17` (...896 at the end!)

If you were to *increase* the original binary number by one, like this:

`0100001101111001010000100101010100101110010000111001001100110100`

Then that equals: `1.13756928537604928E17` (...928 at the end!)

So, there are exact double precision binary representations for these numbers:

`113756928537604896`

`113756928537604912` (closest to actual quotient)

`113756928537604928`

The above can be verified using online converters, such as [here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html).

**So the lesson is:**

Integer division will give the correct answer (i.e. the integer portion of the quotient). Flooring floating-point division relies on binary representation of numbers, which is not always precise.

**Outside of the scope of this answer, but required reading to *really* understand any of this:**

*How do the above binary numbers represent their decimal equivalents?*

- Short answer: IEEE-754. I wish you luck and lot’s of coffee if you plan on studying that standards document.

*What is the algorithmic difference between `/` and `//`?*

- In other words, why does `//` get us the answer we want above?

Comment: To give a little more context, it looks like Lua 5.3 added support for (64-bit) integers. As for why // works but floor does not, my guess is that the latter is implemented using floating point operations, in which case it'll fall prey to what Brian has described, whereas the former apparently uses integer operations.

That being the case, I'm not sure you'll be able to correctly solve this problem with a Lua version older than 5.3 (short of a plugin or library that adds a user-defined 64-bit integer type).

Answer (score -1):

Lua's Numbers are double precision, right? There are increasingly large gaps in the integer representation once you get above 2^52.

568784642688024576 is larger than 2^58, so you may be running into some of those gaps. If that's the case, then it looks like // correctly accounts for the gaps, whereas maybe floor does not.

If it is important that your code handles integer values approaching 2^64, then it might be worth looking for a plugin or something that lets you work in 64 bit integers. Or if you need to deal with even larger numbers, there may be a library or something for working with very large numbers.